# Why fill() compiles when used on 1 dimensional array, but doesn't on multidimensional one

Tags: c++, arrays

So can anybody tell me why this code compiles:

```
int main()
{
    int CCC[1000];
    std::fill(CCC, CCC + 1000, 33);
    return 0;
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
int main()
{
    int CCC[1000][4];
    std::fill(CCC, CCC + 1000*4, 33);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> "incompatible types in assignment of `'const int'` to `'int [4]'`"

Comment: Because parameters are incompatible... int[][] != int[]. You can simulate an multidimensional array using following formula to find position: A[n*i + j]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass pointers to the beginning and one past the end of the range, i.e `int*`:

```
std::fill(&CCC[0][0], &CCC[0][0] + 1000*4, 33);
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right: the array `CCC` is composed of four-element arrays `int [4]`, so you cannot assign `33` to them.

If you are on C++11, you can fix this by switching to `std::array`, creating a temporary `array<int,4>`, filling it with `33`s, and then filling the `CCC` array with that temporary array, like this:

```
array<array<int,4>,1000> CCC;
array<int,4> tmp;
std::fill(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 33);
std::fill(CCC.begin(), CCC.end(), tmp);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/KCXxWf)

Answer (score 0):

What type does `CCC` have? The correct answer is `int **` so a pointer to a pointer pointing to an `int`.

`int[4]` is actually a pointer type, so your compiler expects you to pass a pointer to the initialization argument of `std::fill`. But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: _"The correct answer is int **"_ - Uh no, the correct answer is `int (*)[4]`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious relevant user name